# Error while building Android V2.2[Froyo] Source Code

Tags: android, build, android-2.2-froyo

I'm getting the following error while building the Froyo Code -

```
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE passion
target Generated: libclearsilver-jni <=  out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/clearsilver_intermediates/javalib.jar
target Generated: libclearsilver-jni <=     out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/clearsilver_intermediates/javalib.jar
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c
host Executable: acp (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp)
/bin/bash: javah: command not found
/bin/bash: javah: command not found
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libclearsilver-    jni_intermediates/org_clearsilver_CS.h] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libclearsilver-    jni_intermediates/org_clearsilver_HDF.h] Error 127
true
```

Please help me to find out the root cause for this build error.

Comment: `javah: command not found`: check your java installation

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a PATH issue. For me I had to do

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/
```

To make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

$ uname -m
x86_64
depending upon x86_64 or XXX32
modified the following files to use m64 for x86_64 and m32 for xxx32 in android directory

```
   /external/clearsilver/cgi/Android.mk
   /external/clearsilver/java-jni/Android.mk
   /external/clearsilver/util/Android.mk
   /external/clearsilver/cs/Android.mk
```

Edit the above mentioned files using vi or vim editor.
type
       LOCAL_CFLAGS += -m64
       LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -m64

command in the files below the line "LOCAL_CFLAGS := "

NOTE: If your system is x86_64 download JDK_1.5_update_xx_amd64.bin

Answer (score 0):

Javah is a part of the [JDK](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html&ei=CgvETabCNcnJsgbQxqXEDw&usg=AFQjCNG9HwUyCVwOIeJtJFVQ2YKXrRFNmg&sig2=tbppNo5uxhaVNqIJAdXzAw). Download and install one.

Comment: Thanks for answering Vladimir.But,before I started building,I had already installed JDK/JRE V1.5[which is the version required for building Froyo sources].Even now,when I try installing again,it says-
    package jdk-2000:1.5.0_11-fcs.i586 is already installed
    package jre-1.5.0_11-fcs.i586 is already installed
Is there anything else which I'm missing out?Please suggest..